How to get the header request URL value in Python?
I am trying to download an APK file from apkmirror using selenium, requests, beautifulsoup, and curl to download the file, I get stuck when I reached the download page, then the URL redirects, and a download.php request appears in the inspect devtools in the network that have the direct link for the file.
before
after
I tried to download the file using curl with -L flag to this url:
curl -L "https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-19-16-39-release/youtube-19-16-39-android-apk-download/download/?key=15b5cb3061082b309a0c30f1d2e410704e909596&forcebaseapk=true"
and the curl gets an HTML page and doesn't follow the redirected URL that appears in the image above.

This can be done using python requests library. We need to follow 4 steps to download and save the app from apkmirror.

Fetch the apk page where download button is present and take the download link (inspect on download button to see the link).
Now, fetch the download link (it is like clicking download button) to get some id and key values which can be used to download the actual apk file.
Make a request with the parameters that we extracted from the previous fetch.
Save the response into a file.

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'priority': 'u=0, i',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

apk_url = "https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/youtube/youtube-19-16-39-release/youtube-19-16-39-android-apk-download/"

# Fetching Main APK page to extracting download link
print(f"Fetching APK URL: {apk_url}")
main_page_response = requests.get(
    apk_url,
    headers=headers,
)

main_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page_response.content, "html.parser")
main_page_dom = etree.HTML(str(main_page_soup))
link = main_page_dom.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'downloadButton')]/@href")[0]
download_link = f"https://www.apkmirror.com{link}"

# Fetching download link to get the additional parameters required to download the actual app
print(f"Fetching Download Link: {download_link}")
download_page_response = requests.get(
    download_link,
    headers=headers,
)

download_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(download_page_response.content, "html.parser")
download_page_dom = etree.HTML(str(download_page_soup))
id_value = download_page_dom.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'id')]/@value")[0]
key_value = download_page_dom.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'key')]/@value")[0]

params = {
    'id': id_value,
    'key': key_value,
    'forcebaseapk': 'true',
}
headers["referer"] = download_link

# Making another request with the extracted parameters and headers to download the file
final_url = f"https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id={id_value}&key={key_value}&forcebaseapk=true"
print(f"Making final request to download the file: {final_url}")
print("Please wait for sometime. It depends on the apk file size and internet speed")
apk_response = requests.get(
    'https://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php',
    params=params,
    headers=headers,
)

# Writing response to apk file (mention file path in place of youtube.apk)
print("Saving response to a apk file")
with open('youtube_final.apk', 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(apk_response.content)

print("File saved successfully")


I tried it, but didn't work, even my script didn't work anymore. Before that i abled to get to final_url, now it can't recognize the download button's class
